# How to get data based on 'AND' operator instead of 'LIKE' by using JpaSpecificationExecutorWithProjection's findAll method?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am new to Hibernate.My senior used 'findAll' method of JpaSpecificationExecutorWithProjection (interface) which is returning result based on a 'LIKE' operator but I required result based on 'AND' operator. Please guide me how I can solve this?.

Below is the part of code which displays it is hitting query based on 'LIKE' operator

```
where
        (
            upper(course0_.course_subject) like ?
        ) 
        and (
            upper(course0_.course_sub_category) like ?
        ) 
        and course0_.course_status=? 
        and (
            upper(course0_.course_exam_segment) like ?
        ) 
        and (
            upper(course0_.course_category) like ?
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is using `AND` operator. The `LIKE` is for evaluating your individual params.

If you don't like the JPA-methodqueries, you can always write your own in your repository. Below is a quick example incorporating a left join and returning a Page-object. Please take a look here for some [basic JPQL](https://thorben-janssen.com/jpql/)

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM Product p "
            + "LEFT JOIN p.categories category "
            + "WHERE UPPER(p.name) LIKE UPPER(CONCAT('%', COALESCE(:searchRequest, ''), '%')) "
            + "AND UPPER(p.description) LIKE UPPER(CONCAT('%', COALESCE(:description, ''), '%')) "
            + "AND p.price BETWEEN :priceLow AND :priceHigh "
            + "AND p.averageRating >= :averageRating "
            + "AND p.archived = :archived "
            + "AND ((category.name IN :selectedCategories) "
            + "OR (:amountOfSelectedCategories = 0 AND category IN (SELECT c FROM Category c))) "
            + "GROUP BY p "
            + "HAVING SIZE(p.categories) >= :amountOfSelectedCategories"
    )
    Page<Product> findAllBySearchModel(
            Pageable pageable,
            @Param("searchRequest") String searchRequest,
            @Param("description") String description,
            @Param("priceLow") BigDecimal priceLow,
            @Param("priceHigh") BigDecimal priceHigh,
            @Param("averageRating") double averageRating,
            @Param("archived") boolean archived,
            @Param("selectedCategories") List<String> selectedCategories,
            @Param("amountOfSelectedCategories") int amountOfSelectedCategories
    );
```

Comment: By using this I'm getting correct result but is their any way to handle null value condition using above logic.

i.e Multiple cases like if user fill 'description' get data based on that or else All 
if user fill 'archived' get data based on that else ALL
if user fill 'name' get data based on that else All like all kind of permutation combination (Max parameters are 6 ,    ....user can fill all or some )

Comment: if I understand you correctly, you'll want to take a closer look at the ```COALESCE``` function. It takes a valid param, or the next alternative if param is null. In my example, I used it to make sure I'm searching at a blank String which will return everything in case the user doesn't fill it in. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_coalesce.asp